# What can EF Core 5 translate

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm optimizing an expensive query, and have a hunch part of the problem is premature client side evaluation. I've searched around and am having a hard time finding a clear list of what can be translated into an SQL query for EF Core 5. These are the operations I'm specifically wondering about:

```
.Where(entity => listOfInts.Contains(entity.Id))
.Where(entity => entity.SomeStringProp.Contains("SomeSubsString")
.Where(entity => entity.SomeNullableProp.HasValue)
```

I'm no SQL expert but I could imagine these being feasibly translatable. I just don't know if EF Core 5 is as smart as I hope it is. Any pointer to documentation on this is appreciated.

Comment: EF Core 5 does not have automatic client side evaluation (EF before 3 though [did](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client))  So unless you [explicitly evaluate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#explicit-client-evaluation) on client side (via `AsEnumerable` or `ToList` and their async versions) your query should be translated into SQL (with small exclusion of final projection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core 5 does not have automatic client side evaluation (EF before 3 though [did](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client)) So unless you [explicitly evaluate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#explicit-client-evaluation) on client side (via `AsEnumerable` or `ToList` and their async counterparts) your query should be translated into SQL (with small exclusion of [final projection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#client-evaluation-in-the-top-level-projection)).

Also since you are trying to figure out performance of your query - try checking out the SQL generated by EF. Since 5.0 you can use [`EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.toquerystring?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions_ToQueryString_System_Linq_IQueryable_) to see it (and depending on the database - using profiler or database specific queries/logs).